# Using moment.js in Angular 2 typescript application

Tags: typescript, angular, momentjs, systemjs

I'm struggling in using moment.js library inside an Angular 2 Typescript app. Even after reading the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35166168/1031097) I can't get it to work.

This is what I did so far:

- I installed moment.js using npm, so I can find the library under node_modules/moment/moment.js
- I configured System.js to retrieve moment library:

  ```
  System.config({
      packages: {
        app: {
          format: 'register',
          defaultExtension: 'js'
        },
        moment: {
          main: 'moment.js',
          type: 'cjs',
          defaultExtension: 'js'
        }
      },
      map: {
        moment: 'node_modules/moment'
      }
  });
  ```
- I installed typescript typings with `typings install moment-node --ambient --save` and `typings install moment --ambient --save`, so I can see the correct typings inside typings/main/ambient/moment-node and typings/main/ambient/moment

Now, if in my code I use `import * as moment from 'moment';` typescript compilation run smooth and I can see the correct suggestion inside Atom editor (if I start with `moment().` I can see year(), month(), etc.). However if I run my code inside the browser, it gives an error saying that 'moment is not a function' (debugging I can see that moment is an object with lots of methods).

If I write `import moment from 'moment';` the code in the browser runs fine, however typescript compilation fails with 'module moment has no default export' and I can't get any suggestion from Atom while writing code.

What am I doing wrong? What's the correct way to import moment.js (and any non typescript library) inside an Angular 2 typescript application?

Comment: Try import moment from 'moment';

Comment: Thanks for your reply!
However, as I said in my answer, if I write `import moment from 'moment';` typescript compilation fails and I can't get any suggestion from my IDE when using moment().

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import * as moment_ from 'moment';
const moment:moment.MomentStatic = (<any>moment_)['default'] || moment_;
```

Comment: Great! This works nicely, thanks!

I'm just wondering if there is some way to make the import nicer. I mean: if the moment.js typescript definitions were different, there would be a way to just write moment.default()? If moment.js main file was different, there would be a way to write just moment()? The problem I found with moment.js is tied more to its typescript definition files or to the way it is written?

Comment: This is not right. It works but it is ugly and confusing. The TypeScript compiler supports SystemJS with flags such as `allowSyntheticDefaultImports`.

Comment: This works at runtime, but does not compile within Visual Studio.

Answer (score 5):

As pointed out further down moment ships with its own typings now.
And @angular/cli have changed aswell. Updated my answer to reflect this.

npm i --save moment

```
import * as moment from 'moment';

export class SomeClass implements OnInit {

  date: moment.Moment;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.date = moment();
  }

}
```

is all that is needed with @angular/cli.

**Below is my old outdated answer.**

With angular-cli: So you get Intellisense in VsCode

edit --> angular-cli-build.js

```
module.exports = function(defaults) {
  return new Angular2App(defaults, {
    vendorNpmFiles: [
      ...

      'moment/min/**', // add this line

      ...
    ]
  });
};
```

edit --> system-config.ts

```
const map: any = {
  moment: 'vendor/moment/min/moment.min.js' // add this line
};
```

In your component:

```
import * as moment from 'moment';

...
// example of usage
dates: moment.Moment[] = [];

ngOnInit() {
  let date = moment();
  date.add(2, 'days');
  this.dates.push(date);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Also I found this: 
Install Moment.js using NPM:

```
npm install moment
```

Add it to your SystemJS configuration:

```
map: {
  'angular2': 'node_modules/angular2',
  'rxjs': 'node_modules/rxjs',
  'moment': 'node_modules/moment/moment'
}
```

You also need the interface:
`tsd install moment --save`
and then add:

```
/// <reference path="typings/moment/moment.d.ts" />
import * as moment from 'moment';
```

Comment: Monent ships with its own .d.ts file now. Also tsd is deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

From your index.html add

```
 <script src="../node_modules/moment/moment.js"></script>
```

In your component use:

```
declare var moment: any;
...

this.startDate = moment().subtract(15, 'days').format('DD-MM-YYYY');
this.endDate = moment().format('DD-MM-YYYY');
```

Answer (score 0):

When you import a module using *namespace* syntax to gather the exports onto a single object, as in `import * as moment from 'moment'`, you are not importing the actually moment object which the module exports, but rather all of its members. You are losing the call signature. To resolve this, in a SystemJS + TypeScript project, specify either a value of "system" for module or a value of `true` for allowSyntheticDefaultImports, passing these to the TypeScript compiler, preferably via a `tsconfig.json` file.
Then import moment like so

```
import moment from 'moment';
```

and everything will work.