# Cannot add moment.js or ng2-bootstrap to angular2 project

Tags: angular, npm, ng2-bootstrap

I get this message when my gulp tslint task runs.  I'm not sure how to add moment.js so that ng2-bootstrap is happy.

> node_modules/ng2-bootstrap/components/datepicker/date-formatter.ts(1,25): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'moment'.

[Here](https://github.com/robertdunaway/katas-angular2/tree/master/005%20Angular2%20-%20adding%20bootstrap) is my project on GitHub.  It should work with Visual Studio 2015 with no additional configuration.

I updated my systemjs config as specified:

```
System.config({
  packages: {
    app: {
      format: 'register',
      defaultExtension: 'js'
    }
  },
  map: {
    moment: '../lib/moment/min/moment.min.js'
  }
});
System.import('app.js')
      .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
```

I added this import to my components file.  This is what generates the error.

```
import {BUTTON_DIRECTIVES} from 'ng2-bootstrap/ng2-bootstrap';
```

I'm loading this module with NPM.

```
"moment": "^2.11.2",
```

I'm copying all the library files to wwwroot within my gulp file.  Maybe I need to copy over more files?  I don't know.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use moment.js library in angular 2 typescript app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35166168/how-to-use-moment-js-library-in-angular-2-typescript-app)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make the typescript transpiler happy by adding a few things.

typings install moment --save

Then I made a reference to this in the ts file.
///

I've checked in my changes so you can see it at the github link in the original question.