# App compile error: Cannot find namespace 'moment'

Tags: angular, momentjs

I've been working on my angular 2 app yesterday and everything ran fine.
Today I was trying to `npm start` my app and I get this compile error:

```
typings/browser/ambient/moment/index.d.ts(9,21): error TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'moment'.
```

Although I didn't mention anything releaeted to `moment` in my app!

What can cause this error if I'm not using anything releated to `moment`?

I tried:

1. [The solutions here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35166168/how-to-use-moment-js-library-in-angular-2-typescript-app)
2. `npm remove moment`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had the same problem. Just fixed it.

When you run:

```
typings install moment --ambient --save
```

You'll likely see an info message like this:

> typings INFO reference Stripped reference "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/56295f5058cac7ae458540423c50ac2dcf9fc711/moment/moment-node.d.ts" during installation from "moment"

This was my clue that I also needed to install the typings for `moment-node` and then everything worked.

```
typings install moment-node --ambient --save
```

Good luck!

Comment: @Eusthace, the `--ambient` flag was replaced by `--global`, and you now have to specify the source (definitely typed = `dt~`).  The following worked for me:  `typings install dt~moment-node --global --save`.