# Making moment injectable in angular2

Tags: angularjs, angular

I would like to make moment to be injectable through out my app.
I just started learning ng2 and couldn't find this type of usage in the docs.
Here is what I have in my `app.module.ts`:

```
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import {HttpModule} from '@angular/http';
import {AppComponent} from './app.component';
import * as moment from 'moment';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule
  ],
  providers: [{provide: 'moment', useValue: moment}],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

and here is the component:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.sass']
})


export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app works!';

  constructor(private moment) {
    this.title += this.moment;
  }
}
```

there is this error:

```
Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for AppComponent:
```

How should this be done correctly?

**UPDATED MODULE**

```
const moment = new OpaqueToken('moment');

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule
  ],
  providers: [{provide: moment, useValue: moment}],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})

export class AppModule {
}
```

**UPDATED COMPONENT**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import * as moment from 'moment';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.sass']
})


export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app works!';

  constructor(private moment: moment) {
    this.title += this.moment()
  }
}
```

There is an error on this line `constructor(private moment: moment)` which tells that: `Cannot find name 'moment'.`

Comment: have you went through [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35166168/2435473)?

Comment: it's not related. I don't want to use it via import. I want to be able to inject it at any class

Comment: are you using `angular-cli`?

Comment: Yes I am using the cli

Comment: Why do you want to inject it via constructor? What is the reason?

Comment: I believe that services should be injectable - easier to unit test

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Moment by itself is not an injectable for Angular2. However it can be wrapped inside one.

[Plunker Demo](http://embed.plnkr.co/NsK17Q/)

**moment.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import * as m from 'moment';
@Injectable()
export class MomentService {
    moment = m;
}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { MomentService } from './moment.service';

@NgModule({
    providers: [MomentService]
    ...
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { MomentService } from './moment.service';

export class AppComponent {
    constructor(private ms: MomentService){
        console.log('Moment:' + this.ms.moment("20111031", "YYYYMMDD").toString());
    }
}
```

Not perfect, but works.

Comment: It's a nice way to handle this. But I am hoping there is a way to do it without a wrapper service. The same way we did in ng1 with constant.

Comment: @vlio20 This is actually the Angular 2 way to do global variable, through injectable service public properties/variables. Check out my [ng2-simple-global](https://github.com/J-Siu/ng2-simple-global) service, there is a plunker link in the readme.md. `moment` here is the *global variable*.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `OpaqueToken` which will allowed you to create a string based token. I'd just suggest you to change the name of `moment` to avoid thr collision with `moment` variable of library.

```
// You can place this is some file, so that you can export it.
export const Moment = new OpaqueToken('moment');
```

and then you could use

```
providers: [{provide: MomentStatic, useClass: moment}],
```

You can go through [this article](http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/05/23/opaque-tokens-in-angular-2.html) for more details

While using dependency include it in a Component constructor.

```
constructor(private moment: MomentStatic)
```

Comment: I am getting the same error. I am probably missing the injection part. Can you please add it to your answer (the injection of moment in the constructor)?

Comment: That's but obivious in A2

Comment: it's just what I did, but there are few questions and problems. I have imported moment (in the component file) like this: `import * as moment from 'moment';` but the I am getting this error: `Cannot find name 'moment'.` at this line: `constructor(private moment: moment)` (see updated question to see the full component (under update)

Comment: have you added `map` for moment in system.config.js

Comment: I am using the angular-cli. It is not required to make any changes to the systemjs configuration. moment is available globally.

Comment: I guess its conflicting with moment variable of moment.js.. try updated answer

Comment: Probably better to use `MomentStatic` instead of `Moment`. But even then, in the component file, from where should I import the `Moment` type (for this line: `constructor(private moment: Moment)`)?

Comment: That's why I said place opaque token in some file & export it when you want to, otherwise you need to define opaque token everytime when you want it

Comment: The problem is that `export const Moment = new OpaqueToken('moment');` is not a type. I can't use it at this line: `constructor(private moment: MomentStatic)`

Comment: Any progress with this one?

Comment: Oh.sorry will look at it in my morning

Comment: @vlio20 I changed `useValue` to `useClass`

Comment: The problem is the injection. You can't specify that the type is const. (you should also update the const Moment to const MomentStatic)

Answer (score 0):

Moment doesn't have to be injected, it is a library that you can "just use". It's enough to import it in your typescript file now you can use moment's features.

Comment: I want to make it injectable. That is the idea of this question.

Comment: Ok, I just don't understand why you would want to do that

Comment: Moment can be used as is, it doesn't need to be injected. It is not an angular 2 service. What you can do is create angular 2 service and wrap moment's methods inside it,or the ones you need.  Then you can inject that service into your components.

Comment: I want to make it injectable. That is the idea of this question

Comment: I understand the question. I don't understand the why behind the question.

Comment: You would want to make a third party library injectable so that you pass in a stub when testing the component. This is one reason to inject it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are loading moment.js so it is available globally how about wrapping it with a service which you can then inject throughout your app?

```
import {Moment} from '../../node_modules/moment';

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

declare var moment: any;

@Injectable()
export class MomentService {
    constructor() { }

    get(): Moment {
        return moment;
    }
}
```

I this way you get the TS IntelliSense when you are coding (at least I do in VSCode) and you can handle mocking moment for testing easily too.

Answer (score 0):

The best workaround that I have come to find is to create a wrapper service, but also expose some of the most common methods directly on the service itself using getters:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import * as moment from 'moment';

/**
 * A wrapper for the moment library
 */
@Injectable()
export class MomentService {
  /**
   * Creates and returns a new moment object with the current date/time
   */
  public moment() { return moment(); }

  // expose moment properties directly on the service
  public get utc() { return moment.utc; }
  public get version() { return moment.version; }
  public get unix() { return moment.unix; }
  public get isMoment() { return moment.isMoment; }
  public get isDate() { return moment.isDate; }
  public get isDuration() { return moment.isDuration; }
  public get now() { return moment.now; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps now but you need something similar (not tested) to the following to make it work in your service.

```
import { Inject } from '@angular/core';

constructor(@Inject(moment) private moment) {
    this.title += this.moment()
  }
```

The key bit is the **@Inject**