# Try to add Stomp over SockJS to angular app: TS2307 Cannot find module

Tags: angular, typescript, requirejs

I've downloaded a working plain-old-javascript example for connecting to websocket Spring channel and I'm struggling with importing this functionality to angular 2 application.

I've added imports to package.json:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~2.2.1",
    (...)
    "stompjs": "2.3.3",
    "sockjs-client": "1.1.1"
  },
```

Then a suggested edit to systemjs.config.js:

```
(function (global) {
    System.config({
        paths: {
            // paths serve as alias
            'npm:': 'node_modules/'
        },
        // map tells the System loader where to look for things
        map: {
            // our app is within the app folder
            app: 'app',
            // angular bundles
            '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
            (...)
            'sockjs-client': 'npm:sockjs-client',
            'stompjs': 'npm:stompjs'
        },
        // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
        packages: {
            (...)
            'sockjs-client': {
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            },
            stompjs: {
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            }
        }
    });
})(this);
```

But when I add the import

```
import {Stomp} from "stompjs";
```

I get the "TS2307: Cannot find module" error message and the code compiled to:

```
var stompjs_1 = require("stompjs");
```

results in invalid http url:

```
http://localhost/myapp/node_modules/stomp-client
```

instead of path to JS file.

What I've made wrong here? I've searched many SO answers, such as here: [How to use moment.js library in angular 2 typescript app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35166168/how-to-use-moment-js-library-in-angular-2-typescript-app) and I've tried to do everything similar. I've also tried alternative import syntaxes like:

```
import * as Stomp from 'stompjs';
```

but nothing works.

How to use both libraries in Angular2?

Answer (score 2):

You need to write the full path to the javascript file in your library, in systemjs.config.js :

For example, for stompjs, according to the repo on Github, it might be :

```
map {
    (...)
    'stompjs': 'npm:stompjs/lib/stomp.min.js'
},
packages: {
    // Remove stompjs from here, because you already have the full path
}
```

After, you can use your library with this syntax :

```
import * as stomp from 'stompjs';
```

You will still have the error `error TS2307: Cannot find module`, but at least it will work in your browser.

I hope it help.

Answer (score 0):

This seemed to fix the error for me:

```
npm install --save-dev @types/sockjs-client
npm install stompjs
```