# Importing moment.js

Tags: ionic2, angular-moment

I am following this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35166168/how-to-use-moment-js-library-in-angular-2-typescript-app) how to import and use moment in Ionic 2 RC5.

But it cant find the file. My improt is in src/index.html:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Ionic App</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
  <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
  <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">

  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="assets/icon/favicon.ico">
  <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#4e8ef7">

  <!-- cordova.js required for cordova apps -->
  <script src="cordova.js"></script>


  <!-- un-comment this code to enable service worker
  <script>
    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
      navigator.serviceWorker.register('service-worker.js')
        .then(() => console.log('service worker installed'))
        .catch(err => console.log('Error', err));
    }
  </script>-->

  <link href="build/main.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<body>

  <!-- Ionic's root component and where the app will load -->
  <ion-app></ion-app>

  <!-- The polyfills js is generated during the build process -->
  <script src="build/polyfills.js"></script>

  <!-- The bundle js is generated during the build process -->
  <script src="build/main.js"></script>
  <script src="node_modules/moment/moment.js" />

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: if you want to add it as a script in the index ( not advised ) you need to go one more level up ../node_modules/moment/moment.js

Answer (score 12):

To use momentjs on ionic2 according to [this](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/use-it/typescript/) link:

1- `npm install moment --save`

2- in your .ts file:

```
import * as moment from 'moment';
```

and for example:

```
ngOnInit() {
   let now = moment().format('LLLL');
   console.log(now);
}
```