# How to use Momentjs in Ionic 4 view

Tags: html, angular, ionic-framework, momentjs

How can i use [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/) in ionic 4 view?

in calendar.page.html moment is unresolved

```
  <p>{{moment().getDay()}}</p>
```

> Unresolved function or method moment()

in calendar.page.ts i can use moment

```
import * as moment from 'moment';
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Importing moment.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41875104/importing-moment-js)

Comment: Have a look at [ngx-moment](https://github.com/urish/ngx-moment)

Comment: @Roy this did not helped me to use momentjs in my view

Answer (score 1):

Your current code is not working because right now your view is looking for a method `moment` in your controller. I see two solutions:

1) Add a function to your controller which interacts with MomentJS:

In your controller add:

```
getMomentDay() {
    return moment().getDay();
}
```

Next in your view change the line to this:

```
<p>{{ getMomentDay() }}</p>
```

2) Use an Angular plugin which exposes MomentJS the Angular way like [ngx-moment](https://github.com/urish/ngx-moment).