# "moment" has no exported member 'default'

Tags: angular, typescript, momentjs, angular7, angular-moment

I'm using `moment.js` to change the local date format for my application but getting the following error:

> "moment" has no exported member 'default' when importing the library.

Below is my code:

```
import {Inject, Injectable, Optional} from '@angular/core';
import {DateAdapter, MAT_DATE_LOCALE, MatDateFormats} from '@angular/material';
import * as _moment from 'moment';
import {default as _rollupMoment, Moment} from 'moment';

const moment = _rollupMoment || _moment;
```

Comment: Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35166168/how-to-use-moment-js-library-in-angular-2-typescript-app)

Comment: Version of moment?

Comment: @dileepkumarjami   "moment": "^2.24.0"

Comment: Did you try adding the above ?

Comment: @dileepkumarjami Thanks you for the quick replay -   added just , but still error exist - one improvement is now it's not showing any redline  for default keyword I'm using

Comment: Try to re-run your project after trying *@dileepkumarjami*'s suggestion, because it's necessary when you change *tsconfig.json*

Comment: @dileepkumarjami - you are right needs to recompile i think :) thanks it's working

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Try adding `"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true` to your `tsconfig.json` under the "compilerOptions"

Comment: adding in tsconfig yes, but in which part of the tsconfig? root? compilerOptions? lib?

Comment: In the `compilerOptions` section

Comment: adding to `tsconfig.app.json` worked, not `tsconfig.json`

Comment: this solution worked for me in Angular 14. I had issues with wagmi/core

Comment: Also you have to importing moment  >> `import moment from 'moment';`

Answer (score 7):

You seems to have trouble importing **moment**

As you can see [in the documentation](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/use-it/typescript/), 
For **Typescript 2.x** try adding `"moduleResolution": "node"` in `compilerOptions` in your `tsconfig.json` file and then use any of the below syntax:

```
import * as moment from 'moment';
import moment = require('moment');
```

PS: Make sure you have installed `moment.js` with `npm`:

```
npm install --save moment
```

Comment: I'm having problem with word 'default'.

Answer (score 4):

Here you go with a complete solution to this problem:

First:

```
 npm install moment --save
 npm install @angular/material-moment-adapter
```

Second:

in your package.json under dependencies make sure you have the following code:

```
    "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "^8.2.3",
```

Third:

in your tsconfig.json file under compileroptions add the following:

```
"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
```

Forth:

Modify your component with the following codes:

```
import { MomentDateAdapter } from '@angular/material-moment-adapter';
import { DateAdapter, MAT_DATE_FORMATS, MAT_DATE_LOCALE } from '@angular/material/core';
import * as _moment from 'moment';
import { default as _rollupMoment } from 'moment';

const moment = _rollupMoment || _moment;
export const MY_FORMATS = {
parse: {
  dateInput: 'LL',
},
display: {
  dateInput: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
  monthYearLabel: 'YYYY',
  dateA11yLabel: 'LL',
  monthYearA11yLabel: 'YYYY',
 },
};

@Component({
 selector: 'app-newsfeedform',
 templateUrl: './newsfeedform.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./newsfeedform.component.css'],
 providers: [
  { provide: DateAdapter, useClass: MomentDateAdapter, deps: [MAT_DATE_LOCALE] },

  { provide: MAT_DATE_FORMATS, useValue: MY_FORMATS },
],
})
```

Fifth:

In your component.html file datepicker like bellow code:

```
     <mat-form-field appearance="outline" fxFlex>
                    <input matInput [matDatepicker]="publishdate" placeholder="Publish Date"
                        formControlName="publishdate">
                    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="publishdate"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
                    <mat-datepicker #publishdate></mat-datepicker>
                </mat-form-field>
```

That is it you can customize Angular material datepicker any format you want just modify the format given above.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following line in the `tsconfig.json` file:

```
"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
```

Answer (score 0):

in **gulpfile.js** in *externals section* add `'moment/moment'` and `'moment'` both

```
externals: [
      'moment/moment',
       'moment'
   ]
```