# General bindings for Angular TypeScript of a Javascript library

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, binding

Javascript has a plethora of libraries. Some have bindings, some don't. Being able to use them in TS is obviously a huge plus for TS.

The basic steps to use the JS library within angular seems to be creating a set of bindings, or installing them when available.

I would like to know for a JS library that do not have proper bindings (yet):
- What is the most natural way to create such bindings?
- How to include the Javascript library in an Angular TS project?
- How to link the bindings to the Javascript and to Angular?

This concerns recent Angular/TS. What are the current best practices regarding these questions?

As a reference, here is the case of moment.js

[How to use moment.js library in angular 2 typescript app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35166168/how-to-use-moment-js-library-in-angular-2-typescript-app)

Answer (score 0):

If there is not related `@types/some-module` module in npm you can create declaration file and specify things there.

**decs.d.ts**

```js
declare module "some-module" {
  var someObject: any; 
  export default someObject;
}
```

Make sure typescript knows about it

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "include": [
    "src",
    "decs.d.ts"
  ]
}
```