# Change API data in Angular

Tags: angular, angular12

Im having a difficult time, from API im getting data like

```
{ 
id: 1, 
name: 'name', 
startTime: '1640153700', 
endTime: '1640159100'
},
{ 
id: 2, 
name: 'Name2', 
startTime: '1640153700', 
endTime: '1640159100'
}
```

startTime and endTime is in Timestamp from API
and on Angular Component im printing it as

```
<div *ngFor="let d of data;let i=index">
<p>{{d.name}}</p>
<p>{{d.startDate *1000 | date:'dd MMM YYYY' }}</p>
</div>
```

//Component.ts

```
constructor(
   private _services:ApiService,
) { }

data:any=[];

this._services.data().subscribe((result)=>{
 //console.log(result);
 this.data= result;
})
```

Instead of Printing the Dates, i want to check if with the startTime is Today or Tomorrow

Tried doing a `*ngIf="d.startTime = d.this.todayDate"` i dont think this is right

```
this.todayDate = this.datepipe.transform(this.currentDate, 'dd MMM yyyy');
```

and bunch of other things that didnt work,
Basically, i Need to Check

if `startTime is Today`, Then print `Today`,

if `startTime is Tomorrow`, Then Print `Tomorrow`

and if `current date and time is between startTime and endTime`, then Print `Live`

Comment: try to use [moment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35166168/how-to-use-moment-js-library-in-angular-2-typescript-app) for your project, he can condition dates

Comment: Don't use moment it's deprecated (more [here](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/)). You might want to look [here](https://blog.logrocket.com/4-alternatives-to-moment-js-for-internationalizing-dates/) for alternatives