# convert string date to datetime format in Angular / Typescript and compare it with current date

Tags: angular, typescript, datetime, typescript2.0

I'm new to angular and I need some help in datetime conversion.
My datetime in string is `Sat, 30 Apr 2022 00:00:00 GMT` but I want to compare this date (only `Sat, 30 Apr 2022`) with current date.

How do I fetch only date and convert it to datatime format in GMT and compare it with the current date?

Answer (score 0):

u can use [momentjs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43257938/7103430) library for what

also u can set the format of string what u put like below:

```
moment(YOUR_DATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
```