# angular date format inside the html

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Currently date is display like below
[image]

I need to format this date like,
Date of Loss: 08/07/2022 (DD/MM/YYYY)

This is my HTML code. I need to do it inside the HTML page. Is it possible?

```html
<label class="col-form-label font-weight-bold">
    {{_modalViewData.dateOfLoss}}
</label>
```

Comment: there's this on angular <https://angular.io/api/common/formatDate> or this library <https://momentjs.com/> and here is how to use it with angular <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35166168/how-to-use-moment-js-library-in-angular-2-typescript-app> have you tried any of those?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use pipes. Pipes provide you the possibility to change the transform the string without changing the value itself.

```html
<label class="col-form-label font-weight-bold">
    {{_modalViewData.dateOfLoss | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy'}}
</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Angular Date Pipe functionality for transform date to any specific format

https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe

```
{{_modalViewData.dateOfLoss | date : 'dd/MM/YYYY'}}
```